# what is the scope of document.domain()?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, same-origin-policy

I understand if we have payment.example.com and news.example.com and they both set document.domain to exmaple.com they can communicate. However, what if en.news.example.com opt-in and set document.domain=example.com? is it also possible to communicate?

Comment: What is: en.news.example.com opt-in?

Comment: means en.news.example.com add to the page document.domain=example.com

Answer (score 0):

**Document.domain**

Gets/sets the domain portion of the origin of the current document, as used by the same origin policy.

The [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) restricts how a document or script loaded from one origin can interact with a resource from another origin. It is a critical security mechanism for isolating potentially malicious documents.

Example :

```
// for document www.example.xxx/good.html,
// this script closes the window
var badDomain = "www.example.xxx";

if (document.domain == badDomain)
   window.close(); // Just an example - window.close() sometimes has no effect.
```

---

```
var domain = document.domain;
```

Changing the value of this property is the easiest way to work around the limitations that the same origin policy applies when your pages are on different sub-domains of the same site. While JavaScript would normally consider pages from blog.example.com and from forum.example.com to be from different origins and so not allow JavaScript from one to interact with web pages from the other, you can resolve this particular restriction by setting the document.domain in both pages to the same value. By setting the document.domain to the shortest version of your domain name in all of your scripts you would allow your JavaScript to communicate across all of the pages of your site regardless of protocol, sub-domain or port.

Comment: Thanks but it did not answer my question. can a sub sub domain star communicating if it adds document.domain=example.com? e.g more.blog.example.com

Comment: @JauL The answer is yes. Try going [here](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/) and running `document.domain = 'whatwg.org';` in the inspector.